# integer input within a range in django

Tags: django, html, input

My django model needs a field which should have input ,the integers 1 to 10.I modelled this as below

```
class Review(model):
    ...
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=5,help_text='value 1 to 10')
```

I am providing forms for creating and editing a Review as below

```
class ReviewForm(ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model=Review
    ...

class ReviewEditForm(ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model=Review
    ....
```

What should I do to make sure that user inputs an integer 1 to 10 ..Should I check for this in clean method of forms ? Or is there a better way?

Ideally I want to show the field as a slider which is available in html5 (`RangeInput` I think),which shows as a `slider` in `chrome` and `textfield` in  `firefox16.0.2ubuntu`.But I don't know how this can be done without javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use django validators for the job

```
from django.core.validators import *

rating = models.IntegerField(default=5, help_text='value 1 to 10', validators=[MaxValueValidator(10),
            MinValueValidator(1)])
```